# KnockoutJs: dataObject is not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple WebApi project to manipulate returned data in various format. I am trying to use KnockoutJs to consume the data at the front end but I am having a variable not defined error that I can't seem to understand why. Below is the simple code I am working on. Please feel free to point out the errors. Thanks

Controller formats

```
[httpGet]
public Object Data
{
  return new {
   Time: DateTime.now,
   Text: "<b>Salut</b>",
   Count: 1
  };
}
```

JS front end

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax("/api/formats", {
       success: function(data){
          dataObject = ko.observable(data);
          ko.applyBindings();
       }
    };
 });
```

HTML

```
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Time</td>
         <td data-bind="text: dataObject().Time">
         <td>Text</td>
         <td data-bind="text: dataObject().Text">
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Pedram Sorry for the delayed response, I just modified the binding of the variable as you advised and it worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first,your variable `dataObject` does not have `Time` and `Text` properties, so you should check it in your code as following:

```js
var dataObject = ko.observable();
ko.applyBindings();
  
function doBinding() {
    var data = {
        Time: "XYZ",
        Text: "<b>Salut</b>",
        Count: 1
    };
    
    dataObject(data);        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>

  <div data-bind="text: dataObject() ? dataObject().Time : 'No Data'"></div>
  <div data-bind="text: dataObject() ? dataObject().Text : 'No Data'"></div>
  
<div>

<button onclick="doBinding()">binding</button>
```